# Why CALCULATE is not modifying filter context when used with FILTER?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with 2 measures - `One and Two`. Both uses CALCULATE and have a filter. There's also a slicer.  While `Two` rightfully ignores slicer's filter context, `One` doesn't.

'Years'[Year] is a Whole number.

`One = CALCULATE(SUM(Years[Sales Amount]),FILTER(Years, 'Years'[Year] = 2010))`

`Two = CALCULATE(SUM(Years[Sales Amount]),'Years'[Year] = 2010)`

What am I missing (in my learning)?  I understand Microsoft recommends to NOT use FILTER as filter argument. I'm merely trying to get a grip on the way it works.

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-avoid-avoid-filter-as-filter-argument

Answer (score 10):

There are some tricky details on `CALCULATE` that produce different results. I’ll show the differences and provide examples below.

---

### Measure One

```
One = CALCULATE(SUM(Years[Sales Amount]),FILTER(Years, 'Years'[Year] = 2010))
```

First, remember that every language calculates from the most internal to the most external function.

It means that Power BI will first calculate the function `FILTER`, which will return a table that contains only the year 2010. Only after that Power BI will perform `CALCULATE`.

**A tricky part here**: If there is a filter in the 2nd parameter, the `CALCULATE` can ignore the slicer (more details on measure two). However, there is no filter on the 2nd parameter, there is only a table! (previously calculated, which contains only year 2010 now).

Since there is no filter, `CALCULATE` applies the [context filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-overview#filter-context) (the slicer in your example) excluding anything before 2013.
Given that, no rows match the filters for Measure One and the result will be blank (if the slicer is set to 2013-2018, of course).

### Measure Two

```
Two = CALCULATE(SUM(Years[Sales Amount]),'Years'[Year] = 2010)
```

Measure Two do have a filter expression: 'Years'[Year] = 2010

When filter expressions are provided, the `CALCULATE` function changes the filter context (which contains slicers or filter on page etc.) to evaluate the expression.

For each filter expression, there are **two potential outcomes** in `CALCULATE`:

**Outcome A.** If the columns are already in the filter context, the existing filters will be overwritten by the parameter in the `CALCULATE` expression. I.e., does not matter the slicer (or filter *on this page* or *on all pages*…)

That is the case for your measure two!

Since you are using 'Years'[Year] in both the `CALCULATE`  expression and the slicer, the context filter will be overwritten by the filter in the `CALCULATE` expression. I mean, the result is ignoring the slicer/filter context and you will find "3" as the result.

**Outcome B.** If the columns aren't in the filter context, then new filters will be added to the filter context to evaluate the expression. In other words, it will consider both the slicer/filter context and the filter expression in `CALCULATE`.

To exemplify this behavior, I have created a new measure:

```
ThreeSalesFilter = CALCULATE(SUM(Years[Sales Amount]), 'Years'[Sales Amount]=3)
```

It keeps the exact same row as measure two, right? The Year=2010 is the same row Sales Amount=3.
However, the result of this measure is blank and not 3. Quite interesting!

Again, it happens because `CALCULATE` is using 'Years'[Sales Amount] but the slicer/filter context is using 'Years'[Year] – another column. Therefore the `CALCULATE` filter "joins" the filter context; do not overwrite it.

*Below, the reproduction of the dashboard including my third variable.*

[image: Dashboard reproduction]

*If you need more details or clarifications, please let me know in the comments and I'll edit here.*

Answer (score 1):

You are getting different behaviors because of the way that the [`CALCULATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) function works with filter context; you are passing two different types of arguments into the calculate function.

- In measure one you are passing a table filter expression. It takes the table created by the [`FILTER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-function-dax) function, and then applies the filter context given by the slicer. Table filter expressions [do not override the existing filters](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/table-filter-expression-in-CALCULATE-function/td-p/2141446) on any columns.
- In measure two you are passing a Boolean filter expression as the second argument. It **overrides** the filter context since they both filter based on the `year` column, therefore ignoring the slicer.

[MS best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-avoid-avoid-filter-as-filter-argument) do caution against using `FILTER` as a filter argument, but they do also mention examples of several times where it is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

- I try to create a table like yours

[image]

- also create the two measures which build on the dashboard
  [image]

So, I think the values displayed by **One** and **TWO** are not the same as the DAX syntax. But your **One** is BLANK that the possible reason is that **One** caught the filter condition on the right side of your way, while **TWO** caught the value of the table on the left, I guess it is because it's not the same.